# Ruby Fibonacci custom function

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

I am trying to write a simple custom function for fibonacci, But i am getting a error:

My code :

```
class Fibonacci
 def fib(num)
  @num = num.to_i
  series = Array.new
  series[0] = 0
  series[1] = 1

  for i in 0..series[@num]
    series[@num+2] = series[@num] + series[@num+1]
  end
  return series
 end
end

obj = Fibonacci.new
obj.fib(8)
```

Error :

```
ruby fibonacci.rb
fibonacci.rb:9:in `fib': bad value for range (ArgumentError)
from fibonacci.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Sidenotes: `to_i` and `return` are unnecessary here; `series = [0,1]` can replace lines 2 to 4 in your method definition; use two spaces for indentation throughout; `for` is not idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: sure @sagarpandya82, will refactor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `ArgumentError` from `0..series[@num]`, where `series[@num]` will be `nil` at that point.

I think you meant to have:

```
for i in 0..@num
  series[i+2] = series[i] + series[i+1]
end
```

Comment: To avoid the 2 extra items, you could change the loop to `2.upto(@num) { |i| series[i] = series[i-2] + series[i-1] }`